# Choosing Photos and Taking from camera on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm using the same .h and .m files for both iPhone and iPad xibs. I would like to capture an image or choose from photos on tap of a button. How do I do this? If I choose from photos on a pop over, I get the photo gallery but doesn't select the photo and the camera doesn't open if I choose from camera! Everything works fine on iPhone, though. Here is the code I'm using:

```
-(IBAction)getPhotos:(id)sender
{
    self.action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take New Photo",@"Choose From Existing",@"Remove Photo",@"Cancel", nil];
    self.action.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;
    self.action.destructiveButtonIndex = 2;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        [self.action showInView:self.view];
    }
    else
    {

        [self.action showFromRect:self.button1.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];

    }
}


-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)popup clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self TakePhotoWithCamera];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        [self SelectPhotoFromLibrary];
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_photo.png"];
    }

}

-(void) TakePhotoWithCamera
{
    [self startCameraPickerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];
}

-(void) SelectPhotoFromLibrary
{
    [self startLibraryPickerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (BOOL)startCameraPickerFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller usingDelegate:(id<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>)delegateObject
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.delegate = self;
        [controller presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)startLibraryPickerFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller usingDelegate:(id<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>)delegateObject
{
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.delegate = self;
     if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
     {
             [controller presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

    else
    {
        popover=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:picker];
        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.imageView.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickers didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    self.imageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
}
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
-(IBAction)getPhotos:(id)sender
{
    self.action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take New Photo",@"Choose From Existing",@"Remove Photo",@"Cancel", nil];
    [self.action showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
}


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    switch (buttonIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            picker.allowsEditing = YES;
            picker.delegate = self;
            [self.navigationController presentViewController: picker animated: YES completion: nil];
            break;
        case 1:
            picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            picker.allowsEditing = YES;
            picker.delegate = self;
            [self.navigationController presentViewController: picker animated: YES completion: nil];
            break;
        case 2:
            self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_photo.png"];
            break;
        default:
            [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
            break;
    }
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
     self.imageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
   //  [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: If u like my answer so please accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get button index like this,
In your delegate method of actionsheet,

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)popup clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
switch (i) {
        case 0:
        {
           [self TakePhotoWithCamera];
        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            [self SelectPhotoFromLibrary];
        }
            break;
        case 2;
        {
            //no image
        }    
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps u.